# Git - Change remote branch

Tags: git, heroku, github, branch, git-remote

I have the following:

```
$ git remote show production
  Fetching repository, done.
  ...
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master     merges with remote master
    production merges with remote production
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master     pushes to master     (up to date)
    production pushes to production (up to date)
```

But I need the following where my local branch `production` is pushed to my remote branch `master`. How can I change that ?

```
$ git remote show production
  Fetching repository, done.
  ...
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    production merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    production pushes to master (up to date)
```

**Edit**

If I try

`git branch --set-upstream production production/master`

I have this strange result ("staging" is another remote environment I use):

`Branch production set up to track remote branch master from staging.`

Answer (score 1):

Set the upstream branch of your local production branch to origin master.

```
git branch --set-upstream production origin/master
```

Comment: My remote branch is called "production", so if I try `git branch --set-upstream production production/master`, I have this strange result `Branch production set up to track remote branch master from staging.` ("staging" is another remote environment I use)